# Musician (Guitarist?) finds "muse" at party, but muse is "drained" of energy by musician

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alternate-history

... Spoiler alert ...

A male musician, possibly a guitarist, in his 20's meets a girl at a party and she is his "muse".  However, in this world muses are "drained" of energy by the musician.  His friend drags him away from the party to ensure he doesn't drain the muse to death.  However, the musician sneaks back the next day as he is irresistibly drawn to her...

The two friends also discuss ways to get the best from a muse: Only visiting the muse once per month(?); the musician is supervised at all times; all the music that is created at the visits is recorded; and the musician attempts to write music in between visits.

Set in our current (alternate) world.  Written in English.  Prob in one of the "Best SF of 20xy" anthologies (Dozois? Strahan? Best Aussie SF?).  I read it in the last 2-3 years. Prob set in the US...

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: You can use >! to add a spoiler quote.